# Virtualenv python path pointing to anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I have an issue with an old virtualenv project after I installed Anaconda:

1. Cloned my project from GitHub.
2. `source bin/activate`
3. `which python`

The output is /Users/myuser/anaconda/bin/python, I expect the output to be my local virtualenv python path e.g. myproject/python.

I'm a Python novice, don't have a clue on how to fix this? Should I uninstall Anaconda?

Comment: What is the command promp after you execute `source bin/activate` ?

Comment: `(venv)` is prefixed to my prompt, so I think that the activate script ran succesfully.

Comment: Command `conda info --envs` will list all available environments. The one with asterisk is the active one. Try it to see what you have.